# Multiple storyboards not working

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I am using this code to load each storyboard depending on screen but the only one that works is 480 and all the others are not working there just blank

How can i fix this
Thanks

```
 var window: UIWindow?

    func grabStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard {
        var storyboard = UIStoryboard()
        let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        if height == 480 {
            storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main3.5", bundle: nil)


        if height == 568 {
                storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main4", bundle: nil)
            }


        if height == 667 {
                storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main6", bundle: nil)
            }

        if height == 736 {
                storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main6plus", bundle: nil)
            }
        } else {
            storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        }
        return storyboard
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = self.grabStoryboard()

        self.window?.rootViewController =
            storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()! as UIViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use Storyboards like that, any change that you do to one you'll have to apply to all of them, increasing the risk of error. I suggest you lear to use Auto Layout and have the UI layout depending on the screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You need to use `if-else` statements in a right way like the following. You can check Swift documentations [Swift Control Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html). Go for the section `Conditional Statements`.

```
func grabStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard {
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard()
    let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    if height == 480 {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main3.5", bundle: nil)
    } else if height == 568 {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main4", bundle: nil)
    } else if height == 667 {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main6", bundle: nil)
    } else if height == 736 {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main6plus", bundle: nil)
    } else {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    }

    return storyboard
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The if for 568, 667 and 736 are inside the 480 statement, so they will never be reached. Hope that helps.